# How to Update Specific Columns Only based on HTML Form Value in Laravel 7

Tags: mysql, database, laravel, sql-update, crud

I'm trying to update specific database table columns based on my HTML form input text value. In my `OrderHistoryController`, I'm allowing customers to cancel an order for my e-commerce website project. Thus, I'm updating the status and the `cancel_notes` columns. I was able to do this.

In my Controller I have this cancel method:

```
public function cancel(Order $order)
{
    $order->status = 'canceled';
    $order->save();

    //check if all suborders are canceled
    $pendingOrders = $order->where('status','!=', 'canceled')->count();

    if($pendingOrders == 0) {
        $order->update(['status'=>'canceled']);
        $order->update(['cancel_notes'=>'cancel_notes']);
    }

    // send mail to customer that order was completed
     Mail::to($order->user->email)->send(new OrderCanceled($order));


    return redirect('/order-history')->withMessage('Order was canceled');
}
```

How can I modify this line `$order->update(['cancel_notes'=>'cancel_notes']);` to fetch text value from my 'cancel_notes' input textbox instead of having literal value 'cancel_notes' upon updating?

Thanks a lot in advance! :)

Answer (score 0):

Supposing you have a form in which user writes down cancellation  notes in this case you can do

```
public function cancel(Order $order, Request $request)
{
    $order->status = 'canceled';
    $order->save();

    //check if all suborders are canceled
    $pendingOrders = $order->where('status','!=', 'canceled')->count();

    if($pendingOrders == 0) {
        $order->update(['status'=>'canceled']);
        $order->update(['cancel_notes' => $request->cancel_notes]);
    }

    // send mail to customer that order was completed
     Mail::to($order->user->email)->send(new OrderCanceled($order));


    return redirect('/order-history')->withMessage('Order was canceled');
}
```

> I'm supposing your input name will be `cancel_notes`

Other way to do this instead of injecting `Request` class you can use `request()` helper function like so `request('cancel_notes')`